# Negative language

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm doing an Language Analysis Essay and am struggling to find a word that describes negative language (as in bad language, negativity ect.) as an effect (as you would use to create sympathy in the reader). Any ideas??? E.g. The article uses ____ effectively as an example of negative language.

Comment: Hi, C J. Welcome to EL&U. Please edit your question with full context as your question is not clear as it stands. Thanks.

Comment: As an effect? ... How intriguing.

Answer (score 2):

The noun 'pejoration' might fit in your sentence. I should mention, however, that in order to comprehend your meaning I rewrote your model sentence slightly, to

> The article uses **pejoration** effectively to example the negative language.

The rewrite from "show" to "example" may not be justified; without further context, it's impossible to know with any reasonable degree of certainty if "example" is the sense of "show" that you intended.

The relevant portion of the definition of 'pejoration' is this:

> 1. Chiefly formal. ... (sometimes) *spec.* depreciation, disapproval, criticism; an instance of this; a depreciatory or critical expression.

["pejoration, n.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/139797?redirectedFrom=pejoration (accessed January 22, 2016). *Spec.* is an abbreviation of *specifically*.]

Note that if the audience for your "Language Analysis essay" knows linguistics, some dissonance may arise from the technical use of 'pejoration' in linguistics to mean

> 2. *Linguistics*. The development of a less favourable meaning or of less pleasant connotations for a word or expression.

(op. cit.)

Comment: Or, "... the article uses pejoratives effectively...".  And I wouldn't say "to example", but, if you want that sentence structure, "to demonstrate" or some such,